# How to assign and access the returned list Flutter Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have fetched a list from my firestore collection and now I want to assign it to a list. But flutter is not allowing me to assign the returned value.

Where data is pulled from firestore:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class ImagePull {

  QuerySnapshot? data;
  Future<List> fetchImages() async{


    List<dynamic> value = [];

    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Places').get();
    value = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
    print(value);
    return value;
  }
}
```

Where I want to return list:

```
import '../Reusable/imagepull.dart';
class Travel{
  String? name;
  String? desc;
  String? phn;
  String? url;
  Travel(this.name,this.desc,this.phn,this.url);
  ImagePull img = new ImagePull();

  dynamic List<Travel> generateTravelBlog async(){
    List<dynamic> = img.fetchImages();

    return[{
      Travel()
    }]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `fetchImages()` function has a return type of `Future`, therefore you need to await the result. The fix for that is to simply add an `await` keyword before your call to that function:

```
List<dynamic> result = await img.fetchImages();
```

You forgot to add a name to that variable as well, so be sure to add that. The **result** is important here, you didn't have a name set for that.

EDIT:

You are not parsing the results and you have some errors in your naming:

```
List<Travel> generateTravelBlog() async {
  List<dynamic> images = await img.fetchImages();
  return images.map((image) => Travel(image["name"], image["desc"], image["phn"], image["url"])).toList();
}
```

I don't know if that data exists in your Firestore, I just used the same names as you did in your model, so make sure to use your accessors (e.g. image["your_accessor"])

Comment: it says list isnt a type

Comment: @GauthamKrishna change your return type from `Future<List>` to `Future<List<dynamic>>`

Comment: still same list isnt a type

Comment: @GauthamKrishna updated, but that goes a bit beyond your question. If that does not work, try casting the result by adding .cast<Travel> to the end of the return statement.